# Set file size limit for video on Canon 5D mark iii

Tags: video, video-editor, video-quality, video-recording, dslr

Contrary to what it seems like everyone else is trying to do with their DSLR's, I was wondering if anyone knew how to limit file size for a single recorded file to 2GB instead of the usual rate of 4GB. Due to streaming requirements, I need my recorded files to not exceed 2GB and it's way, way more work to split the files manually. Is anyone aware of a way of accomplishing this on the camera (Canon 5D mark iii) itself?

Answer (score 2):

The 4 gig limitation is there cause most memory cards are formatted with FAT32 which can't handle files larger than 4 gig.

Refer to Manual page 234, http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/8/0300007348/05/eos5d-mk3-im7-en.pdf

The only way to limit the file size, is to limit the recording time.
You can always do the math and find out how many minutes to record to hit 2 gig.

EDIT: the link no longer works.  Here is a screenshot of the page -

[image]